# Where to put gradle-2.2.1-all

Tags: android, android-studio

one of my Android Studio projects was trying to fetch gradle-2.2.1-all.zip from http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip but due to some network errors it could not fetch it so I downloaded it manually from the browser. But now I don't know where to to put it? I am on a pc running windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\ **gradle-2.2.1**

Basically, your main installation of Android Studio.

Comment: Android Studio still Keeps to download it